# Working on dataframe files from a directory

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, dplyr

A newbie here! I have written the following unfinished code:

```
library(dplyr)
filenames <- list.files(path = "~/Desktop/ChIP-Seq", pattern ="*.bed", full.names = T)
mylst <- lapply(filenames, read.table, header = F, sep = "\t")
for (i in filenames)
  x <- nrow(mylst[[i]])

##dont know what to do here
y <- paste("MACS_peaks", seq(from= 1, to= , by= 1), sep = "")
gd1 <- mutate(gendata, MACS_peaks = y)
```

I want to access each file of my directory, run an nrows command for each file, and use that nrows number for each file to use `dplyr` `mutate` and add that many number of `MACS_peaks`, for each file.

How can I do so?

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  Do you want to create a column with number of rows ?  `mylst1 <- lapply(mylst, function(x) x %>%
                             mutate(MACS_peaks = n()))` or with tidyverse `mylst %>% map(~mutate(., MACS_peaks = n()))`

Comment: No sir. I want to know the no. of rows for each file in the directory, and add a column of that specific length for each particular file using dplyr.

Comment: That is what the code above does in the comment.  If you want to have row number, then `lapply(mylst, function(x) x %>% mutate(MACS_peaks = row_number())`

Answer (score 0):

From the OP's code, it seems like we need to create a sequence column of row numbers (`row_number()` is a convenient function from `dplyr`)

```
lapply(mylst, function(x) x %>%
                             mutate(MACS_peaks = row_number()))
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
mylst %>% 
    map(~mutate(., MACS_peaks = row_number()))
```